# Selenium PrintOptions Orientation.LANDSCAPE does not print pdf in landscape mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pdf-generation, selenium4

I want to print page to pdf in selenium 4, in printOptions I set orientation to Landscape mode, Still the pdf will be saved in portrait mode only. Can someone help me where I am making mistake

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String driverPath = "src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe";
    WebDriver driver = null;
        
    System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, driverPath);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
    driver.get("https://google.com");

    PrintOptions printOptions = new PrintOptions();
    printOptions.setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
    Pdf pdf = ((PrintsPage) driver).print(printOptions);
    Files.write(Paths.get("./PDF_Extract/test.pdf"), OutputType.BYTES.convertFromBase64Png(pdf.getContent()));
    }
```

I am expecting a Landscape mode pdf not portrait mode pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

The default page size is - height 21.59cm and width 27.94cm

Just change the page size - height 27.94cm and width 21.59cm

````
PrintOptions printOptions = new PrintOptions();
printOptions.setOrientation(Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
printOptions.setPageSize(new PageSize(27.94, 21.59));
Pdf pdf = ((PrintsPage) driver).print(printOptions);
Files.write(Paths.get("./PDF_Extract/test.pdf"), OutputType.BYTES.convertFromBase64Png(pdf.getContent()));```
````